# Create hive table from JSON data

Tags: json, hive, create-table, hive-serde, hiveddl

I have a file with Json data which takes the below form:

Ex:

```
 {
    "Name": "xxxx",
    "Address": [{
        "Street": "aa",
        "City": "bbb"
    }, {
        "Street": "ccc",
        "City": "ddd",
        "Country": "eee"
    }]
}
```

The above Json is a valid Json. I want to create a hive table on top of data of above form using JsonSerde.

Comment: Make sure your JSON is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Create table with all possible fields defined. If field is not present in json, select will return NULL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE your_table (
Name string,
Address array<struct<Street:string,City:string,Country:string>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
```

if you have names in JSON file which conflict with Hive reserved words then add mapping and rename names in table definition:

`WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('mapping.renamed_column'='original_column')` and rename your table columns.

Put your file in the table location.

See also docs with some examples here: https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

Comment: Probably, my question is misleading. But, infact I need to create a table structure which accepts an Array of different data types. I read this is not possible. But, needed a work around for this.